# ¿Que metodo de machine learning usar para la realizacion de un resumen?

Tags: python, nlp

soy nuevo en el tema de NLP y quisiera saber cual es el mejor metodo de machine learning o deep learnign para la realizacion de un resumen coherente, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente uno de los modelos que más está dando que hablar y que ha sido una revolución en 2019 ha sido **BERT**. Es un tipo de redes neuronales que suele usarse para temas de NLP. También puedes usar los clásicos modelos de deep learning **Word2Vec**, Aunque **BERT** parece estar mejorando estas redes.

Por último te sugiero que te tomes tu tiempo para ir avanzando en temas de Machine Learning y Data Science, ya que estos modelos son muy complicados y hay que tener varios conocimientos previos para entenderlos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza la biblioteca PANDAS y acompáñala con NUMPY

https://pandas.pydata.org/

https://numpy.org/

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.